ionic Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
I developed ionic application and angular (ionic 6 and angular 15), I use awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite and cordova-sqlite-storage for create database sqlite, now I test application with my phone android and i use edge inspect device for debug application , now when I launch page for get data from sqlite It return this error .
enter image description here
code ts for component:
 private dbName: string = '';
public static connection: Connection;
this.searchProvider.getDistricts().subscribe(
                    (res: any) => {
          console.log("res getDistricts")
          console.log(res)

                    },
                    (error: any) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                    );

code ts search service:
public getDistricts(): Observable<any> {
return this.databaseProvider.getDistricts().pipe(
    map(
    (res: any) => {
      return res;
    },
      catchError((error: any) => {
      return throwError(error);
    })
  )
);

}
code provider:
  public getDistricts() : Observable<any> {
    let db = new SQLite();
    return from(
        db.create({
            name: this.dbName,
            location: "default"
        }).then((connexion: SQLiteObject) => {
            return connexion
                .executeSql("SELECT * FROM district ORDER BY name", [])
                .then((data: any) => {                        
                    return data;
                })
                .catch((err: any) => console.log(err))
        }).catch((e: any) => console.log(e))
    );
}

I test my application in device android and i debug in edge inspect device, I search in internet and I found cordova doesn't work with browser, but in my case I test with device android

How are you running the app? Can you show if the browser console is showing a y warning like "Cordova is not available"? This may be the problem.

cordova is available because I run app in device android and only I debug in edge devices inspect and in browser console there is nothing
